# Clickhouse materialized view aggregate ghost rows

Tags: apache-zookeeper, clickhouse

So I'm using clickhouse and here is my current tables architecture.

I have a main table containing my data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE default.Liquidity
(
    `Date` Date,
    `LiquidityId` UInt64,
    `TreeId_LQ` UInt64,
    `AggregateId` UInt64,
    `ClientId` UInt64,
    `InstrumentId` UInt64,
    `IsIn` String,
    `Currency` String,
    `Scenario` String,
    `Price` String,
    `Leg` Int8,
    `commit` Int64,
    `factor` Int8,
    `nb_aggregated` UInt64,
    `stream_id` Int64
)
ENGINE = Distributed('{cluster}', '', 'shard_Liquidity', TreeId_LQ)
```

And I also have a materialized view that aggregate data store it in other table

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW default.mv_Liquidity_facet TO default.shard_state_Liquidity_facet
(
    `Date` Date,
    `TreeId_LQ` UInt64,
    `AggregateId` UInt64,
    `ClientId` UInt64,
    `InstrumentId` UInt64,
    `Currency` String,
    `Scenario` String,
    `commit` Int64,
    `factor` Int8,
    `nb_aggregated` AggregateFunction(sum, UInt64)
) AS
SELECT
    Date,
    TreeId_LQ,
    AggregateId,
    ClientId,
    InstrumentId,
    Currency,
    Scenario,
    commit,
    factor,
    sumState(nb_aggregated) AS nb_aggregated
FROM default.shard_Liquidity
GROUP BY
    Date,
    TreeId_LQ,
    AggregateId,
    ClientId,
    InstrumentId,
    Currency,
    Scenario,
    commit,
    factor


----------------

CREATE TABLE default.shard_state_Liquidity_facet
(
    `Date` Date,
    `TreeId_LQ` UInt64,
    `AggregateId` UInt64,
    `ClientId` UInt64,
    `InstrumentId` UInt64,
    `Currency` String,
    `Scenario` String,
    `commit` Int64,
    `factor` Int8,
    `nb_aggregated` AggregateFunction(sum, UInt64)
)
ENGINE = ReplicatedAggregatingMergeTree('{zoo_prefix}/tables/{shard}/shard_state_Liquidity_facet', '{host}')
PARTITION BY Date
ORDER BY (commit, TreeId_LQ, ClientId, AggregateId, InstrumentId, Scenario)
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192
```

As you might have guessed, the `nb_aggregated` column represents the number of rows that were aggregated to achieve this result.

If I make that query on my Distributed query with a lot of filter in order to find one row

```sql
select
       sum(nb_aggregated)               AS nb_aggregated
from Liquidity
where Date = '2022-10-17'
  and TreeId_LQ = 1129
  and AggregateId = 999999999999
  and ClientId = 1
  and InstrumentId = 593
  and Currency = 'AUD'
  and Scenario = 'BAU'
  and commit = -2695401333399944382
  and factor = 1;

--- Result
1
```

I end up with only one row, therefore if I make the same query with the same filter but one the aggregated version of my table that have been created with the materialize view I should also end up with only one line and with the `nb_aggregated = 1` however I end up with `nb_aggregated = 2` as if he had aggregated my row with another and most of the other value are wrong too.

I understand that my exemple is hard to understand but if you have any lead it will be nice.

Comment: If you want number of rows you probably want to use a count() aggregate function instead of sum?

Comment: Thank for your answer @GeoffGenz, however it's just a exemple I don't want to count line it's also breaking the other values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have ask the same question one the clickhouse repository on github and Denny Crane give me this answer that is working for me here:
https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/43988#issuecomment-1339731917

*In the most of cases MatView group by should match to a storage table* `ORDER BY`

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW default.mv_Liquidity_facet:
GROUP BY Date, TreeId_LQ, AggregateId, ClientId, InstrumentId, Currency, Scenario, commit, factor

CREATE TABLE default.shard_state_Liquidity_facet
PARTITION BY Date
ORDER BY (commit, TreeId_LQ, ClientId, AggregateId, InstrumentId, Scenario)
Your ReplicatedAggregatingMergeTree "CORRUPTS" Currency / factor columns using ANY function
```

*the solution is*

```sql
ORDER BY (commit, TreeId_LQ, ClientId, AggregateId, InstrumentId, Scenario, Currency  , factor)
```

https://den-crane.github.io/Everything_you_should_know_about_materialized_views_commented.pdf